# NKIssue Status not updating after NKAssetDownload completes

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, newsstand-kit

I am currently creating an iOS Newsstand app. In my sample I did I am able to download magazine content. but after the download I check the NKIssue status to ensure the issue content is available to read.
But fate it will fire status as default means no value is set.

I try to set the value once download completes, but status is readonly.

1. How I can manage the issue status?
2. I tried in simulator is that the issue?
3. What all sandbox environment required to develop and test Newsstand application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes status is readonly property and is maintained by Newsstand framework. My applications are using them without any problem. Double check that all the added assets using addAssetWithRequest: are downloaded and moved to location specified by contentURL property of NKIssue.

You can also check downloaded content in app's sandbox location in simulator (~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3/Applications/[app GUID]) It should be inside "Cache" directory.

Except for testing NS background push notification I don't think you need something special.

```
// For debugging - allow multiple pushes per day
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"NKDontThrottleNewsstandContentNotifications"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: Ya, I forget to move the downloaded content to location specified in contentURL.